# Don't serialize fields if it exists further up the tree

Tags: jackson

Lots of my domain objects have a `unit` field. Currently when I serialize, every object outputs the `unit` field:

```
{
  "projects": [
    {
      "name": "project1",
      "unit": "mm",
      "size": {
        "x": {
          "value": 100,
          "unit": "mm"
        },
        "y": {
          "value": 120,
          "unit": "mm"
        },
        "z": {
          "value": 80,
          "unit": "mm"
        }
      },
      "materials": [
        {
          "type": "wood",
          "unit": "mm",
          "size": {
            "x": {
              "value": 100,
              "unit": "mm"
            },
            "y": {
              "value": 120,
              "unit": "mm"
            },
            "z": {
              "value": 80,
              "unit": "mm"
            }
          }
        },
        ...
      ]
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

I need the individual objects to have the `unit` property, because they are sometimes serialized on their own. e.g.

```
{
  "length": {
    "value": 100,
    "unit": "mm"
  }
}
```

But when it is nested in another object that already specifies the `unit`, it leads to an awful lot of duplication.

How can I get jackson to omit the `unit` field if there is already a `unit` field with the same value somewhere further up the tree?

Here are some example outputs I want to achieve using the same instances but just changing what the root object of the serialization is:

```
{
  "projects": [
    {
      "name": "project1",
      "unit": "mm",
      "size": {
        "x": {
          "value": 100
        },
        "y": {
          "value": 120
        },
        "z": {
          "value": 80
        }
      },
      "materials": [
        {
          "type": "wood",
          "size": {
            "x": {
              "value": 100
            },
            "y": {
              "value": 120
            },
            "z": {
              "value": 80
            }
          }
        },
        ...
      ]
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

```
{
  "type": "wood",
  "unit": "mm",
  "size": {
    "x": {
      "value": 100
    },
    "y": {
      "value": 120
    },
    "z": {
      "value": 80
    }
  }
}
```

```
{
  "value": 100,
  "unit": "mm"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can’t add business logic like that in the parser.
You’ll have to massage the data class before the mapper.